# Mongorestore is not working Error Image not fount

Tags: database, mongodb, mongorestore

When I am restoring mongo data from a specific position, then it is giving an error image not found.

```
 ✘ ankitrajpoot@Ankits-MacBook-Pro-2  ~  mongorestore --db z2pNew /Downloads/z2p/
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mongorestore
  Reason: image not found
[1]    17642 abort      mongorestore --db z2pNew /Downloads/z2p/
```

Answer (score 0):

First Switch your openssl

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2q
```

Then

```
mongorestore --db z2pNew /Downloads/z2p/
```